# Replacing only a certain part of URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, c#-9.0

I am facing following problem: I have to change a certain part of URL if it contains a specific match ("siteassets") and transform it into different word ("syssiteassets"). This particular word which needs to be replaced can occur at various order in the URL, so for example once it can be "example.com/siteassets/title/index" and different time it can be: "example.com/de/items/siteassets/title/index".

I have tried my luck with pretty simple approach:

```
if (e.UrlBuilder.Path.Contains("siteassets") && (e.UrlBuilder.Path.Contains(".pdf") || e.UrlBuilder.Path.Contains(".dwg")))
{
        e.UrlBuilder.Path = e.UrlBuilder.Path.Replace("siteassets", "syssiteassets");
}
```

...but since this if statement is in the middleware method through which requests run multiple times, the once changed string goes from "syssiteassets" to "syssyssiteassets".

What is the best way to deal with this? I cannot use REGEX (not my decision).

Comment: Have you tried adding a check to see if it contains "syssiteassets"? If it already contains that, you shouldn't need to enter the if statement, correct?

Comment: looking only for the keyword "siteassets" is going to cause bugs in the future.

Comment: what if for example, a person named a file siteassets.pdf   -- now it renames that file.   You need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

is "siteassets" always surrounded by "/" ? I hope else you might have weird bugs.

So if yes, why not just :

```
e.UrlBuilder.Path = e.UrlBuilder.Path.Replace("/siteassets/", "/syssiteassets/");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work, as sometimes this method receives paths which don't start with "/", but start with siteassets.